# why this weird behaviour by display:inline-block?

Tags: html, css

when i am adding some content inside DIV the display is different then i am adding nothing inside the DIV. why this weird behaviour is happening.

1. with some inner content

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORknc.png

2. without any inner content

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf6hS.png

why this weird behaviour by display:inline-block??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default vertical alignment of inline-blocks is `baseline`. If there is text content, this refers to the baseline of the *last* line of that text. If there is *no* text content, this refers to an imaginary baseline at the bottom of the inline-block, hence the alignment you illustrated with your images. See also the following example:

```css
.x {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="x">aasd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd </div>
<div class="x">b</div>
<div class="x"></div>
```

If you want to avoid this, you can add `vertical-align: top;`;

```css
.x {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="x"></div>
<div class="x">aasd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd </div>
<div class="x">b</div>
<div class="x"></div>
```

Comment: if i use different div with different height, and vertical-align: bottom; so the baseline is decided on the basis of longest height. my question is how can i dynamically change the base line or set my own baseline??

Comment: you can't set your own baseline, you can only change the `vertical-align` setting (top/bottom, baseline etc., see also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)